# How do I uninstall python 3.2.2 on Mountain Lion?

Tags: python

How do I uninstall Python 3.2.2 on my MacBook Pro? I’m using Mountain Lion. Any answers greatly appreciated. I’m a beginning programmer.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: If it's the system version of Python 3, ***DO NOT REMOVE IT!*** Versions of Python from python.org, MacPorts, and homebrew all live quite happily side-by-side. You should never remove or upgrade/modify system programs or utilities unless you really know what you're doing, and even then you should rarely do it. Trust me, from experience :)

Answer (score 1):

If you used the installer from python.org, remove these directories:

`sudo rm -r /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework /Applications/Python\ 3.* /Library/Receipts/Python*-3.*.pkg`

You can see what files are copied by the installer by pressing command-I, or with lsbom:

```
lsbom Python.mpkg/Contents/Packages/*.pkg/Contents/Archive.bom
```

Comment: The python installer also leaves some stuff in */usr/local/bin* that can be deleted, see [sx](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8812564/1683555).